# Найти подстроку в строке с числом и знаками сравнения.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть строка, которая может быть вида 1000 или <1100 или >=1200 или <=1300 или =1000
Нужно разбить данную строку и достать оператор сравнения, который может состоять из одного или двух символов и должен находится перед числом. Число в свою очередь может быть любым целым числом. По итогу выполнения в двух переменных должны быть значения: в первой оператор сравнения, а во второй само число. 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/([<=>]{1,2})(\d+)/
```

Comment: Ваша регулярка работает чуть лучше. Спасибо.

Comment: Пометьте ответ верным, это поможет другим с такими же вопросами.